# Upgrading Magento 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.3.0

**Does anyone know the only different file(s) between Magento 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.0?** I'd prefer to replace the updated files only when upgrading Magento rather than executing the patch file. That way I know exactly what changes are made and can be recorded. Observing the patch file is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patch and 1.9.3.0 are two different things.

**During the last Magento patches, we had the habbit that the new version of Magento was the same as the old version with the patch applied, this is not the case here: 1.9.3.0 != 1.9.2.4 + SUPEE-8788**

Here's a diff between 1.9.3.0 and Magento 1.9.2.4 + SUPEE-8788 : https://gist.github.com/digitalpianism/14a15cd52baede0e5d600e8c653f33e9

Comment: I end up with installing 1.9.3.0 then copied all the extensions and modded files. A lot of pains! Wish Magento could provide the zip file of all modded files only.